# Create model and association in Sequelize and Epilogue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, epilogue

### Desired behaviour

Using Epilogue JS and Sequelize, I have two resources, `Student` and `Course`, that have a m2m relationship. I would like to create a new `Student` and associate that student instance with an existing course.

### The problem

When I `POST` a new student and include course information in the payload, Epilogue/Sequelize will attempt to create the new student and create new courses based on the nested payload. This will cause a validation error because those courses already exist.

### Code example

```
const Student = db.define('student', {
  id: Sequelize.UUID,
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Course = db.define('course', {
  id: Sequelize.UUID,
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

Student.belongsToMany(Course, {through: 'student_courses'});
Course.belongsToMany(Student, {through: 'student_courses'});

const StudentResource = epilogue.resource({
  model: Student,
  endpoints: ['/student', '/student/:id'],
  include: [{
    model: Course
  }];
});
```

I want to POST a new student and associate with an existing course, e.g.:

```
// POST /users/
{
  name: "Sally",
  courses: [
    {id: 123, name: "math"},
    {id: 456, name: "science"}
  ]
}
```

However, Epilogue/Sequelize will fail because these courses already exist:

```
{
    "message": "Validation error",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "id",
            "message": "id must be unique"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very aquinted with how epilogue works, but doing it purely via sequelize, you can use the `set<Association>` methods

Something along the lines,

```
student = model.student.create(/*some properties*/)
student.setCourse(course_id)
```

More about it, in [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5325) issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although your code correctly would set an association using Sequelize, it doesn't map to the way Epilogue creates new models. It calls `model.student.create(someAttrs, include: [{model: Course}]`. Are you aware of an option I can pass into Sequelize's `create` method that disable auto-creation of associations?

Comment: There was a flag, `save` which could be passed to create 
You could search for `save : false` for  association
Something along [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/864) issue.
Though I am not very sure how  it works for n:m relationship

Comment: Or even epilogue for that matter

Comment: How do you get `model`?